# Connecting Java Desktop to Cloud Interface

Tags: java, php, web-services, rest

I have a Java desktop application which stores data into a SQLite db every 10 mins which is stored locally in the user's system. I have a cloud interface to visualize this data which uses PHP and MySQL.

I need to fetch data from the local db of the users. I think I will have to write a RESTful web service in Java so that the database which is locally stored is not exposed and the data is obtained by the web service.

I am a bit confused with this. Am I going in the right direction here?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. Your desktop application can connect to the cloud server and upload its information. You'll need to create an http request in your desktop application.

Comment: Now the java desktop application runs every 10 mins in the system tray and inserts data into the db. So now after the insertion i need to write a web service in Java so that it uploads the required data into the db of the cloud interface? What technologies should i be using for this? JSON for exchange or something similar ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should maybe approach this the other way round, rather than the web service getting data from your local system, your local system should upload its data to your cloud interface, perhaps using a RESTful web service on the server rather than the client.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Now the java desktop application runs every 10 mins in the system tray and inserts data into the db. So now after the insertion i need to write a web service in Java so that it uploads the required data into the db of the cloud interface? What technologies should i be using for this? JSON for exchange or something similar ?

Comment: JSON is compact, and fairly simple to work with, sounds like a good next step.

Comment: and how to write restful web service? using servlets? Since i am very much new to code this...... is there any good tutorial or book on how to do this ?

Comment: This tutorial from IBM should give you a good start http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-restatompp/ Best of luck!